How to upgrade Angular 9 to Angular 15 using Azure DevOps pipeline
I have Angular 15 on Azure server. I have a project having Angular 9, and I need to upgrade it to 15 using Azure DevOps pipeline.
Firstly, when I executed Angular 9 Azure Pipeline, it gave me peer dependency error, which I have resolved by updating package.json taking reference from already running Angular 15 project.
But what is the next step now? When I am trying to execute ng update command using 'npm' step in pipeline, its giving me below error:

Error: Repository is not clean. Please commit or stash any changes before updating.

I do not have access to git to clean it.
And if I try to simply use ng build, it gives me several errors in each and every Repo file, that I need to correct and update according to Angular 15.

Glad to see you in Stack Oveflow. It appears there are different errors reported. It's recommended to focus on one issue on one ticket. And share some code snippet and logs for troubleshooting. Please refer to guide How to ask

For the ng update error, it's recommended to sync up the code between local machine and devops. In DevOps yaml, add clean: true for checkout task to clean the code before fetching.

There is no code on local machine. and yaml is not editable to add any command.

Do you mean you don't have access to modify the pipeline definition(yaml or classic UI)? Also you mentioned you don't have access to git to clean repo. In this scenario, please grant permission firstly then try to fix the error.
